# Route Restriction base on Auth User Type

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, middleware

I have 3 kind of users

- admin-super
- admin
- admin-readonly

I've created 3 Middlewares in `/app/Http/Middleware`
I named them

- AdminSuperMiddleware.php
- AdminMiddleware.php
- AdminReadonlyMiddleware.php

---

I've already registered them in `/app/Http/Kernel.php` as followed

```
    'admin'          => 'App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware',
    'admin-super'    => 'App\Http\Middleware\AdminSuperMiddleware',
    'admin-readonly' => 'App\Http\Middleware\AdminReadOnlyMiddleware',
```

---

I've tried calling them in my **routes.php**

```
    $router->group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'admin-super'] ], function() {
        Route::get('account','AccountController@index');
        Route::post('account/store','AccountController@store');
        Route::post('/view-profile/logo/update', 'ProfileController@updateLogo');
    });

    $router->group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'admin'] ], function() {
        Route::get('account','AccountController@index');
        Route::post('account/store','AccountController@store');
    });

    $router->group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'admin-readonly'] ], function() {
        Route::get('account','AccountController@index');
    });
```

---

**Result**

When I log-in as `user type == admin` and go to :

http://localhost:8888/account

I kept getting 404.

Did I miss anything?

Comment: Refer this gist, https://gist.github.com/drawmyattention/8cb599ee5dc0af5f4246
BTW, keep one laravel 5 tag in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The first matching route is going to be executed.

Comment: How would one go about this issue ? How should I lay out my route file ?

Comment: I think I would just simplify it to one middleware then check the admin type in that one piece of middleware.

Comment: Then, let's say I have only 1 AdminMIddleware.php, now, what should my routes file look like.

Comment: The bottom line is that you shouldn't redeclare the same route because the first match will always be executed. So organize it however you like, just don't redeclare the same route. You could continue to use three separate middleware but do so in such a way that you only have a given route declared once. You could have a generic "admin" middleware group. And then on the routes that require elevated privileges, add more specific middleware.

Comment: And, BTW, you can nest route groups. So you could wrap all the admin routes in a route group that uses the auth middleware.